# How to share GraphQL fragments between node and Gatsby pages?

Tags: webpack, graphql, gatsby

When developing Gatsby pages/views, there's a `graphql` template literal available. Not sure exactly where it comes from.

When creating pages with the Gatsby node api (`gatsby-node.js`), a `graphql` parser is injected into functions such as `createPages`

I'd like to know how can I share GraphQL fragments between the pages and the node part. Ideally, I want both to use the template literal `graphql` so that my IDE could understand it's GraphQL and wire syntax highlighting. Currently my node queries are plain strings passed to a graphql function, and I don't have autocomplete for that. And I end up with query duplication too.

I tried to add/import official graphql parser, without great success, and not sure it's supposed to be done that way.

Ideally I'd like to get rid of the global `graphql` template literal that is available in pages without any import, and have a solution that really imports (or require for older node versions) so that it can be shared safely.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the graphql literal, see this explanation https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-four/#wait--where-did-the-graphql-tag-come-from

On fragments, there isn't a way as it's not something you normally want to do. When you create pages, you're only querying for the IDs to pass to the page component that it needs to query for data. E.g. got a markdown page, you pass the ID to MarkdownRemark node.

Comment: Yes that's right, I may not need to share fragments between node and pages. I think what I missed actually was proper IDE support on node part for which I found a workaround anyway: https://twitter.com/sebastienlorber/status/975381321655693314

Comment: It's still hard to avoid duplication sometimes. For example I want to create page URLs based on category and tag information inside the page, which is duplicating logic I use elsewhere when I load the page.
I can live with the duplication, just not happy with "not something you normally want to do"!